# DynamoDB - Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::NotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In rails 5, I am using dynamodb feature by referring https://assist-software.net/snippets/how-save-data-amazon-dynamodb-using-ruby-on-rails and https://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-amazon-dynamodb-with-ruby

When I try to load the root page it shows an error like,

```
Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::NotFound in Admins::SessionsController#new
```

In session_controller.rb

```
def new
  login_aws
end
def login_aws
  ENV['AWS_REGION'] = "us-east-1"
  dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(access_key_id: "xxxx", secret_access_key: "xxxxx", region: ENV['AWS_REGION'], endpoint: "http://localhost:3000")
  response = dynamodb.scan(table_name: 'admin')
  @admin = response.items.take(1).inject(:merge)
end
```

My gems are,

```
 aws-sdk (2.10.19, 1.67.0)
 aws-sdk-core (2.10.19)
 aws-sdk-resources (2.10.19)
 aws-sdk-v1 (1.67.0)
```

Server log shows an error is like,

```
 Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::NotFound ():

 app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb:32:in `login_aws'
 app/controllers/admins/sessions_controller.rb:6:in `new'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Your code is overriding the DynamoDB service endpoint to use a local endpoint. Are you actually using DynamoDB Local (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) and is it running?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to connect to a DynamoDB instance running on `"http://localhost:3000"`:

```ruby
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
   access_key_id: "xxxx", 
   secret_access_key: "xxxxx", 
   region: ENV['AWS_REGION'], 
   endpoint: "http://localhost:3000"
)
```

Given you are setting the `AWS_REGION` environment variable to `us-east-1`, it looks like your intention is to instead connect to the DynamoDB service managed by Amazon, remove the last argument to `Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new`:

```ruby
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
   access_key_id: "xxxx", 
   secret_access_key: "xxxxx", 
   region: ENV['AWS_REGION']
)
```

In fact, your `region` argument is what the SDK uses by default, so you should be able to reduce your client initialization block to:

```ruby
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
   access_key_id: "xxxx", 
   secret_access_key: "xxxxx"
)
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html

Answer (score 0):

you are trying from localhost. Then you need to setup AWS sam local there you can test your API local then you do't do't need secret key and access key. but you are using from AWS cli then you need to required secret key and access key in this way 
And in this module you need to define region

dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
   access_key_id: "xxxx", 
   secret_access_key: "xxxxx", 
   region: ENV['AWS_REGION'], 
   endpoint: "http://localhost:3000"
)